# Loading model validations from a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a superclass with default validations and subclasses that can override the default validations.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  FIELDS = [:field1, :field2]
  after_initialize :include_rules

  def include_rules
    FIELDS.each do |field|
      self.class.send(:validates, field, presence: true)
    end 
  end
end
```

Ignoring the subclasses that will inherit from the superclass...

Each time a form is submitted, after_initialize gets called and the validations are duplicated.

I.e. submit the form 4 times

Output:

```
field1 can't be blank
field1 can't be blank
field1 can't be blank
field1 can't be blank
field2 can't be blank
field2 can't be blank
field2 can't be blank
field2 can't be blank
```

Is there any easy way to load validations only once but from calling them in a method?

Comment: `after_initialize` is probably not the callback you want: It will be triggered at each time the object is found and instanciated. Maybe you meant to use `before_create` or `before_save`

Comment: Same problem when using before_create, before_validation, and before_save.

Comment: Why are you defining these validations on initialize? You can already create a subclass (inheritance) and have them work for the subclassed object.

Comment: I want to be able to override the validation rules in the subclass, i.e. sometimes I may not need to validate :field1 depending on the subclass

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Did not use this solution in the end.

Hmmmm, anyone have a better solution than this?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@validations_ran = 0 
  FIELDS = [:field1, :field2]
  after_initialize :include_rules

  def include_rules
    if @@validations_ran != 1
      FIELDS.each do |field|
        self.class.send(:validates, field, presence: true)
      end 
      @@validations_ran = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Concern?

```
module Smoresable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :marshamallow, presence: true
    validates :graham, presence: true
    validates :chocolate, presence: true
  end
end
```

and use it in your 'child' class like so :

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Smoresable
end
```

For classes where you want to customize it, just add the ones you need, if the list is short  enough... or create additional concerns with other groupings of validations

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong track.  This is what I ended up doing as my final solution:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = "foos"

  def self.defaults
    include_fields
    include_rules
  end

  def self.include_fields
    store :custom_fields, accessors: self::FIELDS
  end

  def self.include_rules
    self::FIELDS.each { |field| validates field, presence: true}
  end
end

class SubFoo < Foo
  FIELDS = [:bar, :bar1, :bar2] 
  defaults
end
```

And now I can create SubFoo instances using the parent default validations that I can choose include or not include.